# Having Facebook likes accumulate over https:// and http://

Tags: facebook, http, https, facebook-like

We're experiencing a problem where Facebook likes are counted individually for http://urlhere.com and https://urlhere.com.

Is there a way to have those counts combine, and just register for the url urlhere.com, regardless of prefix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Point an og:url meta tag on both URLs to one of them (i.e on both HTTP and HTTPS, point the og:url tag to the HTTP version)

Comment: Is this still a valid answer? I have both http and https pages pointing to the http og:url but the likes are counted separately.

Comment: This is still the correct answer if you're not pointing the like buttons on both sites (e.g. HTTPS and HTTP) at the same URL (e.g. HTTP)

Comment: @Igy my new url is https://example.com/product/300 and old was http://example.com/product/300 then according to your suggestion I need to place 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/product/300" /> on my new page head section ?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook for god knows what reason treats these URL as different URLs. If you switch the whole site to https://, which is what people are doing now due to Google's recent announcement, you WILL lose all your like for http:// URL. Facebook will not follow 301 redirect and keep the likes from the http:// URL.

Comment: I have a website, bachecubano.com where in the http version it has 6645 likes, but in the https versio only 791. Why facebook do this?

Comment: @neosoft2014 I'd say that;s because your site is available on both http and https URLs. You should 301 redirect http to https. That's the best practice unless you have a very specific reason to have the site available on both protocols but I can't see why you would.

Comment: OK, I know the https version has more privacy & security &SEO improvements. but the SSL certificate was acquired in two month ago, and the website is two years old. So, with a 301 redirect from http to http I loose the 6645 likes? Sorry my english, I'm cuban

Comment: I guess you can use the method from the excepted answer. So, even though your site is on https:// you can use http:// address in og:url. As far as I can see this is still an issue that hasn't been resolved. Unless Facebook has some kind of admin tools that will allow you to merge the likes and set the preferred URL. It's been a couple of years since the last time I looked at this. I'm sorry I can't be of more help.